# Deactivating toolbar items

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How are toolbar items deactivated/activated?

I would like to make a few buttons visible but not selectable. How is this done if the toolbar items are set as follows.

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: shareButton, space, copyButton, space, deleteButton, nil];

[self setToolbarItems:items animated:NO];
```

I want to activate/deactivate the share, copy and delete buttons when no items are selected.

How are these items accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that spring to mind:

1. UIBarItem has a property on it, tag, that you could set as different for each of the items you want.  Then, when you need to enable/disable one of the items, get the items array, find the one with the appropriate tab then enable/disable it.
2. You could just have some ivars, each one pointing to a different button.  When you need to enable/disable one of them, just use the ivar to get at it.

Comment: Use the "enabled" boolean property of UIBarItem (which UIBarButtonItem is a subclass of)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have some outlets set up and then simply set the enabled properly

```
[myUIBarItem setEnabled:NO];
```